# When removing list bullets with list-style-type: none, how to ensure each item is on a new line?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I added list-style-type: none; to ui style, and it's fine if every list element is about the same length they will all be on their own line. but if one item is very long, it display this:

```
1.a2.b3.c
4.ddddddddddddd
5.e6.f7.g
```

Why is it like this? and how to fix it?

here's my css:

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could provide a snippet instead :) It would be easier to work on your code then :D

Comment: @evgenios95 i added the css I have. is that enough?

Comment: No, it is not. You need to show a proper [mre] of issues like this. _Just_ removing the list bullet would not make list items creep up together next to each other in one "line" to begin with - so you must have other formatting applied as well, that we don't have seen yet.

Comment: @CBroe got it. You're right. I had an inline float style. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

everything is good, so where is the issue?

maybe your `li` tag has inline property, then write this in your css `li{display: block;}`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>ddddddddddddddddddd</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  I had an inline float style causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of styling the ul tag, styling th li tag instead.

So:

```
li {
   display: block
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  I had an inline float style causing the issue.